# Extracting data from a tree

Tags: java, api

> ```
>                            T                 
>                            |
>                        |       |
>                      Animal  Plant
>                        |
>                    |       |
>                Dog   Cat  ..
> ```

I have a tree structure like above, which I need to parse. I am trying to design an API that will let people read this tree. The way I want to accomplish this by letting people specify objects of their interest in this tree and return them. For instance, if I am interested in cats, I want my extractor method to return all cats. If I want to know about all animals, I want to return all animal objects.

I figured I can do something like this-

```
    TreeDataExtractor extractor = new TreeExtractor();
    extractor.registerLivingThingOfInterest(LivingThings.ANIMAL);
    extractor.getData();
```

Now, this method `getData()` will return different types of objects everytime. One time, it could return `Plant` another time it could return `Cat`. So, Should I  just make it return a `LivingThing`? If I make it return a superclass type, should the caller apply a cast in his code? Wouldn't it be a little ugly? Or, should I just design multiple methods `getCats()`, `getAnimals()` with different concrete return types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use genericity to make the method return different types. The user will just have to specify the class as a parameter, for instance:

```
public <T extends LivingThing> T getData(Class<T> clazz, Object otherParam) {
    // insert code here
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
Cat c = getData(Cat.class, otherParam);
Dog d = getData(Dog.class, otherParam);
```

Comment: should it be `getData<Class<T extends LivingThing> class, Object param)` ?

Comment: @Jay no I don't think so. The filter after the visibility modifier already narrows the possible types. Also, I believe what you wrote raises a syntax error.