# instanceof doesn't seem to work - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, instanceof

In continuation to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151294/extracting-data-from-a-tree), I am trying to write a method that goes like this

```
public <T extends LivingThing> T getData(Class<T> clazz, Object otherParam) {
    if(clazz instanceof Cat) {
        //do something and return a new Cat
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error "Incompatible conditional operand types" on the if condition. What am I doing wrong? How do I check for class type in my method?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I made a code change to make use of isAssignableFrom method. Here is a new problem.

```
public <T extends LivingThing> List<T> getData(Class<T> classType) {
        LivingThingEnum livingThing = LivingThingEnum
                .getLivingThing(classType);
        if (livingThings.keySet().contains(livingThing))
            return livingThings.get(livingThing);
        return null;
    }
private Map<LivingThingEnum,List<? extends LivingThing>> livingThings;
```

This gives me a type mismatch! - "cannot convert from List to List". Isn't T supposed to be extending LivingThing, then in which case why does the compiler throw an error?

Comment: You should consider a polymorphic interface where each `LivingThing` has a getData method classes like `Cat` override. It's a much cleaner approach. Using `instanceof` is code smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method takes a `Class<T> clazz` **not** an instance of `LivingThing`.

Either change your method to:

```
public <T extends LivingThing> T getData(T livingThing, Object otherParam) {
    if(livingThing instanceof Cat) {
        //do something and return a new Cat
    }
}
```

Or use the [`isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method on `Class` to test with the `Class` rather than an instance:

```
if(Cat.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
```

Answer (score 5):

`instanceof` operator works on objects, not on classes.

For example if you have variable `obj` you can write: `obj instanceof Cat`. In your case you want to check the following: `if (Cat.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Class#getName()`

```
public static <T extends LivingThing> T getData(Class<T> clazz, Object otherParam) {
    if (Cat.class.getName().equals(clazz.getName())) {
        System.out.println("cat");
        // do something and return a new Cat
    }
    ...
}
```

or try with `Class#equals()`

```
if (Cat.class.equals(clazz)) {..}
```

Comment: Anything wrong with `isAssignableFrom`? Comparing on strings is not only messy but gives the wrong answer - `"Test" instanceof Object` will return true - your test will not.